# Appsettings.json equivalent in Azure C# functions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure C# function which will be deployed to different environments through pipeline. So I need to conveniently store settings parameters for each specific environment.

For example in Asp.Net Core there are `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.Production.json`. 
I am looking for something similar in Azure functions.

Note: these settings should also go to source control.

Answer (score 2):

Locally you obviously have local.settings.json for development settings, once you go to azure you’ll need to create settings on the functions app service itself. To do this in a source control friendly way to can use ARM templates, these allow you to create your function infrastructure which can include settings and their values. Because ARM templates are idempotent you’re therefore able to simple add a setting or change its value and reapplying the template will only apply the change you made in the current release.